# SendMessage to 64bit application is not working

Tags: c++, sendmessage

I use the following function to send message to application. It seems to work find for a 32bit application but doesn't work for a 64bit application (the 64bit application does not seem to get any message). What is wrong and how can I fix it? Thank you.

```
void MyTest::SendCmd(HWND hwnd, QString cmd)
{
COPYDATASTRUCT data;
data.dwData = FIXHEADER;
data.cbData = cmd.size()+1;
data.lpData = cmd.toLocal8Bit().data();

LPARAM lpdwResult;
LRESULT err = SendMessageTimeout(hwnd, WM_COPYDATA, 0, (LPARAM)&data, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 2000, &lpdwResult); 
}
//FIXHEADER is a fixed hex value that the application checks against to make sure the message is sent intentional for it.
```

Comment: Are you trying to send message to another process's windows handle?

Comment: Yes. The message is sent from my program to another application (32bit or 64bit). The other application is specified by windows handle. The windows is win 7 64 bit.

Comment: May be this helps: Did you notice that [`SendMessageTimeout()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644952(v=vs.85).aspx) is actually a macro which expands to `SendMessageTimeoutW()` or `SendMessageTimeoutA()`. ("W" for wide chars i.e. Unicode, "A" for ANSI) To which it expands is _defined_ (in the C sense of word) and depends on some property of your VS settings. However, the types of the arguments might be dependent on this also.

Comment: This cannot work, I think. The other application only receives the values of `wparam` and `lparam`; `SendMessageTimeout` does not know that `lparam` is actually a pointer, and that there is more data intended to be transferred.

Comment: The posted code works if the target application is 32 bit application but it does not work if the target application is 64 bit. I tried the SendMessageTimeoutW() and SendMessageTimeoutA() but none works either... Any other idea? Thanks.

Comment: This one seems to have two problem. inter-process memory access and 32-64 bit pointer structure. Even though you did resolve the first one, second one is not that easy to come over i guess.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile your application in 64-bit mode otherwise this cannot work and 64-bit handles are truncated making them invalid.

Some reading for you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/32-bit-and-64-bit-interoperability